# Swift: Use a button outside of a tableview and check which row was selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

I have a tableView. It's not the tableViewController. On my ViewController I have a tableView with 15 options. I can select each option with no problem. So I want to use a button not inside of the view controller and when I selected it, it determines which row of the table is selected. For now I am just having an alert message appear with what row is selected.

Basically each row of the table is a different race: Dwarf, Elf, ect... Right below the table view is a button. When I click that button I want an alert to appear saying which row has been selected.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class raceViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{

    @IBOutlet var raceInfoBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var raceTable: UITableView!

    // defines an array with the races
    let races = ["Dwarf", "Elf","Gnome","Half-Elf","Half-Orc","Halfling","Human", // core races
                "Ifrit","Oread","Sylph","Tengu","Undine", // featured races
                "Kitsune","Nagaji","Wayang"] // uncommon races// uncommon races

    // defines the stats array to correspond to the races array
    let stats = ["+2 Con & Wis, -2 Chr","+2 Dex & Int, -2 Con","+2 Con & Dex, -2 Str","Click to add","Click to add","+2 Dex & Chr, -2 Str","Click to add", // core races
                "+2 Dex & Chr, -2 Wis","+2 Str & Wis, -2 Chr","+2 Dex & Int, -2 Con","+2 Dex & Wis, -2 Str","+2 Dex & Wis, -2 Str", // featured races
                "+2 Dex & Chr, -2 Str","+2 Str & Chr, -2 Int","+2 Dex & Int, -2 Chr"] // uncommon races// uncommon races] //core

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(races.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "raceCell")
        //cell.textLabel?.text = races[indexPath.row] + stats[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = races[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = stats[indexPath.row]

        return (cell)
    }

    @IBAction func raceInfoBtn(_ sender: Any)
    {
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator", message:
                "dwarf", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

In the `IBAction raceInfoBtn` is where I want it to check which row was actually selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raceTable.indexPathForSelectedRow` should give you the selected index path, which you can use to display the correct information in your alert.

Comment: sweet thanks. Took me a moment to figure it out. I just did a print of that that looked at the console. Now to move on to the next thing.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood, you have 15 choice and each row has it's own button, so 15 button is there.
you would like to get on touchUpInside event get the selected row's.

so you have to add button in your tableviewcell's content view.

now in cellForIndexPath method you have to addTarget at your function, and give the tag as its indexPath.row.

now access each selected row as tag of sender!!

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "raceCell")
    //cell.textLabel?.text = races[indexPath.row] + stats[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = races[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = stats[indexPath.row]
    cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(raceInfoBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
    return (cell)
}

@IBAction func raceInfoBtn(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator \(sender.tag)", message:
            "dwarf", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not even remotely correct. I have one button that is NOT part of the table view. Samantha, solved it for me above.